# Mysql high memory usage and using swap

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mysql, redhat

I have a 1.6GB database that adds about 200MB of size every month. I have a 12GB RAM(shared with apache, mysql and os), mysql always uses swap that i need to restart the service once it reached the swap space limit. The typical memory usage of mysql process is 3.5GB and increases to 4.5GB when there's alot of activity on my web server.

1. How can I avoid mysql using swap?
2. Is 3.5GB mysql process memory usage for a 1.6GB database size normal?
3. My mysql config looks like this, are my configuration optimize?

> ```
> [mysqld]
> innodb_file_per_table
> datadir=/var/lib/mysql
> tmpdir=/var/lib/mysqltmp
> socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> skip-locking
> skip-name-resolve
> table_cache=3072
> thread_cache_size=16
> back_log=100
> max_connect_errors=10000
> open-files-limit=20000
> interactive_timeout=30
> wait_timeout=40
> max_connections=100
> skip-name-resolve
> max_allowed_packet=16M
> tmp_table_size=1768M
> max_heap_table_size=1768M
> query_cache_size=64M
> sort_buffer_size=1M
> read_buffer_size=1M
> read_rnd_buffer_size=8M
> join_buffer_size=32M
> key_buffer_size=64M
> myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
> innodb_log_file_size=100M
> innodb_buffer_pool_size=1512M
> ```

Comment: Best way to analyze your mysql config is to use tools like mysqltunerl.pl. It is simple perl script download it from web and run it will analyze your config and results you with changes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you do load testing and capacity planning for databases?](http://serverfault.com/questions/350458/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-databases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely culprit are these settings:

```
tmp_table_size=1768M
max_heap_table_size=1768M
```

These mean that every individual temporary table created by a query on your website could take up to 1768 megabytes of memory, or 1.7 GB.

I would decrease these to 64M. This will decrease memory usage, but it could also cause MySQL to write temporary table data for queries to disk, which would slow things down.

If MySQL uses disk a lot for temporary tables, you need to analyze your application and find out where the queries are that generate large temporary tables, and then refactor the code so that large temporary tables are not required.