# Question about server usage, big community platform

Tags: web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

I’m working on a community platform writen in PHP, MySQL.

I have some questions about the server usage maybe someone can help me out.

The community is based on JQuery with many ajax requests to update content.
It makes 5 - 10 AJAX(Json, GET, POST) requests every 5 seconds, the requests fetch user data like user notifications and messages by doing mySQL queries.
I wonder how a server will handle this when there are for more than 5000 users online.
Then it will be 50.000 requests every 5 seconds, what kind of server you need to handle this?

Or maybe even more, when there are 15.000 users online,  150.000 requests every 5 seconds. My webserver have the following specs.

Xeon Quad 
2048MB
5000GB traffic

Will it be good enough, and for how many users?

Anyone can help me out or know where to find such information, like make a calculation?

Comment: Hi, Json. This could be classed as a "shopping" question which is off-topic for the StackExchange network. All we can say, really is *it depends*, you'll need to do benchmarks and tweak where nessecary to work out the load capabilites.

Comment: Have you benchmarked your server with `Apache Benchmark`, `JMeter`, `siege` or similar software? Your question is pretty much impossible to answer, since we have no idea how lightweight or heavy your application is.