# LAMP servers performance: Can I improve them by adding more RAMs?

Tags: mysql, lamp, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

Let me refine my questions:
1. How can I improve MySQL performance?
2. Will adding more RAMs help?
3. Will server 1 (details below) get bogged down even with more RAMs?

My setup:
Server 1 - Dual-core Xeon, 1GB RAM (max 8GB), LAMP (as image cdn server, not really using the M part)
Server 2 - Quad-core Xeon, 8GB (max 24GB), LAMP (as main server, AMP running exclusively on this server)

Current situation:
Server 1 (top command) - rather free, not much happening, CPU utilization is idle most of the time
Server 2 (top command) - heavily loaded with MySQL (where mysqld can take 100-175% CPU utilization easily)

My plan is to do primitive MySQL load balancing between the two servers (edit PHP and channel say 40% of mysql queries to Server 1).

Answer (score 1):

100-175% CPU on a 4 core machine isn't necessarily an issue.  Performance improvement has to follow this process,

1. Baseline - know what your performance stats are with a given workload, in fact, with several well defined workloads (i.e. 0 connections, 100 connections, 10 queries, 5 users, whatever makes sense).
2. Change - make a change, there are many tuning options for mysql which you need to read up on, mostly around cache sizes.
3. Re-baseline - after making the changes, rerun your tests to see how it behaves now.

There's no magic bullet with performance tuning, especially when you don't tell us anything about your application.

Comment: My application is my own custom cms and a wordpress blog. Actually your #1 makes sense. I will do a study on my server's baseline performance to see if that is expected (as you mentioned 100-175% on quad-core is not to be alarmed).