# Moving from VPS to Dedicated Server. AMD (vps) vs Intel Dedicated

Tags: centos, vps, dedicated-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

I want to move from VPS to Dedicated Server I guess that VPS specifications are not equal to Dedicated Server and I predict that Dedicated server can make more work with less power.

**Current VPS usage:**
CentOS 6.2
Plesk 10.4.4
I use IP Board forum (3.3), that use a lot of database connections (150+ simultaneous connections for now)

**Current VPS specs option 0:**
AMD Opteron 6128 8-Core Processor with 2.0GHz, 6400MHz HT, 8 x 512KB L2 Cache
I use just 4 cores at 2,5Ghz (total) with 3GB RAM

**Dedicated Server option 1**
Intel Core i3 2130, 2x2(HT)x3.4+ GHz, 3 MB L2
16 GB RAM

**Dedicated Server option 2**
Intel Core i5-2400, 4x3.1+ GHz, 6 MB L2 - QPI 5 GT/sec 
16 GB RAM

The price I pay now for my **VPS abstraction** is the same as the **option 1**.
My question is it's equivalent the power of CPU of **option 0** vs **option 1**. Which has more power? The pick of usage now is 75-95% depends of the day. It will be low with Dedicated Server option 1 and with option 2?

I dont expect exact benchmark info, I just want some suggestion about the difference. Will I note the difference at the change? Any related info will be appreciated.

Comment: I would go for Dedi 2, but none of this seems like server class hardware to me. But if you want to minimize load go for option 2

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 should be good especially that you are coming from VPS and it has considerable amount of RAM that should help your database if you tune it accordingly. Your IO performance should also improve.

Just make sure the storage is on RAID.

What is the CPU and RAM on your VPS? This will help guesstimate performance change.

Comment: You may want to look at -- http://www.anandtech.com/show/5553/the-xeon-e52600-dual-sandybridge-for-servers/14

Comment: I use just 4 cores at 2,5Ghz (total) with 3GB RAM