# managing web traffic by replicating that website into cloud

Tags: mysql-replication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

Can we manage traffic on a website by replicating that into a cloud after the highest possible load on that site?

Like a website can allow 7000 user to surf on that site (this may be according to data traffic) without any trouble loading pages smoothly and when the count reaches 7001 it starts to take some time loading pages and hanging sometimes. So when this happens the site should make a exact replica of itself in cloud and it should work like the original one without any trouble shifting extra traffic into replicated site.

Comment: what's the site written in?  Is it custom code, or something off the shelf?

Comment: You need to find out what's causing the slowdown -- throwing resources at the problem only helps if you throw them in the right spot.  Generally yes - you can get more performance by scaling up (or out), but whether that will work ***for your situation*** is something you need to determine for yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Services such as Amazon EC2's [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) can accomplish this for you. Once you have your web app set up on EC2, it's pretty easy to get set up; Amazon's docs cover it in depth.

Other "cloud" services usually will have similar features.