# Rule of thumb in RAM estimate for static pages?

Tags: debian, web-server, performance, lighttpd, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

I've seen tutorials saying they can run decent websites on 64MB RAM (Debian/Lighttpd/PHP/MySQL) however it's not clearly defined how much hits/traffic a "decent" site gets.

Is there a rule of thumb on how much RAM a web server needs? To keep things simple, let's say you're running a site with static content and it's averaging at 100,000 hits per hour (HTML + images combined, no MySQL). How much RAM is the minimum requirement for that?

Comment: MySQL is a memory hog, even at it's smallest configuration it's going to take up more than half of that 64MB.

Comment: @ChrisS Thanks for pointing out duplicate, it's actually a good duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the average page size for your site that is being served. Then determine, on average, how many unique pages are being presented to users at a time. From there, it's simple multiplication.