# EC2 + RDS, or just a bigger EC2?

Tags: windows, sql-server, iis, amazon-ec2, rds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

I need to develop a system that connect to multiples outter systems to get XML data and reply with computed XML data. Should I go with EC2 + RDS, or just a bigger EC2 ?

Maybe relevant data: DB size is about 50GB, monthly server data transfer is between 120 and 150 GB.

EC2 is WinServer, RDS should be SQL Server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

General rule: keep your data separated from your application.  There are many reasons:

- You can have multiple instances of your application working from the same data set
- Upgrading your application will not affect your data
- CPU is dedicated to one thing: data for data, application for application, choose appropriate sizes for each
- Having read-only replicas for performance boosts

Once you've done that, then it's a question of:

- EC2 Application server + RDS SQL Server, or
- EC2 Application server + EC2 SQL Server

That answer to that purely comes down to management and whether you want to be responsible for that or not (applying patches, setting up read-only replicas, setting up multi-AZ, etc.)

RDS allows you to easily set these up.  But you're limited to what RDS provides.  Running your own SQL Server gives you more flexibility, but you have to manage everything.