# Apache worker is crashing after 3.000 users

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, vps

I activated Apache Worker on my VPS and I'm having problems, 'cause the website is crashing when 3000 users are accessing the website.
I'm using http://whos.amung.us/stats/2jzwlvbhvpft/ as counter.

My Apache Worker configuration:

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
KeepAliveTimeout 1

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
ServerLimit 20000
StartServer 8000
MinSpareThreads 10400
MaxSpareThreads 14200
ThreadLimit 5
ThreadsPerChild 5
MaxClients 20000
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
</IfModule>
```

The VPS have the SO: Debian 64 LAMP, memory: 14gb and CPU: 24ghz

What I could to do to give a best performance?

Comment: Did you try changing the `MaxRequestsPerChild` to something like 1000 ?

Comment: Also, what is the average size of the apache process size on your server ?

Comment: Thanks by your feedback.. I will try the MaxRequestsPerChild to 1000. But, what means "average size of the apache process size on your server" ????

Comment: Apaches spawns several processes to serve your clients. Each process consumes an amount of memory. You can get a list of processes sorted by their memory consumption:
    ps -ylC apache2 --sort:rss

Comment: Also, is apache currently crashing with the worker mpm, our it's not any more?

Comment: But there is no stack overflow on linux. Seems like the "apache requests" are being queued , then I have an 404 error on browser.  So I type F5, then website is displayed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You don't get a 404 if you are being queued, it just keeps the connection open until it's served or timed-out.


I am getting a bit confused, can you please explain what is the status now? Is apache still crashing with worker mpm ?

Comment: Start by reducing Min spare threads to, say, 800 and seeing what happens.

Comment: melsayed, when the webiste are with 3000+ users, apache starts to be unstable. The memory usage/total memory is 6500mb/14000mb. Then, say for each 5 pageviews that I request on browser, 2 returns the 404 error after some seconds trying to access the website.

Comment: David, I was using the Min spare threads between 500 anda 1000, but the "apache crashes" was starting with 1500 users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](http://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this configuration for starters (quite a lot for a VPS server):

```
MaxClients 2000
ThreadsPerChild 50
ServerLimit 40
```

This give you 2000 threads and 40 processes (50 threads per process) to handle max 2000 clients simultaneously.
If you want to increase ThreadsPerChild to value greater than 64 don't forget to change ThreadLimit also.

Comment: <IfModule mpm_worker_module>
MaxClients 2000
ThreadsPerChild 50
ServerLimit 40
</IfModule>

And I delete the other vars (MinSpareThreads, MaxSpareThreads)???

Comment: yes, you can delete those.

Comment: Good, I'll try this tomorrow!

Comment: FINESEC - There is no any effect in the performance. I used this configuration: <IfModule mpm_worker_module> MaxClients 4000 ThreadsPerChild 50 ServerLimit 80 </IfModule> When the website was with 2,500 simultaneous users, it started to crash again. I'm using only php (without mysql). The memory usage was 1300 in use/7400 total Any idea?

Comment: Try to delete all those directives (default configuration will be used). If it still crashes then there's something wrong with your server / apache installation.

Comment: Cool. I'll try it on the next saturday. What could to be wrong with server/apache on your opinion? I'm using vsp.net with Debian 6.0 LAMP x64 and 1 + 17 daily nodes (Dedicated CPU 21.6GHz, RAM 7280MB and Bandwidth 2.7TB).

Comment: Usually you can blame 3rd-party apache modules, server hardware (RAM) or 3rd party "security" software that messes with memory allocation / syscalls. If properly configured apache does not crash when handling too many connections (it just returns errors).

Comment: FINESEC - Fine =/ KeepAlive On with 1 second is good or I need to turn off the KeepAlive?

Comment: 1 second is too short, try 10-15 instead.

Comment: Hey, look this: http://i49.tinypic.com/9r831t.jpg http://i46.tinypic.com/21ozceb.jpg http://i45.tinypic.com/5mzt54.jpg how it's possible? The third link (5mzt54.jpg) uses this <IfModule mpm_worker_module> MaxClients 4000 ThreadsPerChild 50 ServerLimit 80 </IfModule> and first/second uses old configuration.

Comment: Check your apache logs, you can't really say much just by viewing those stats.

Comment: Hm.. I was seeing, It's normal. The vps have 5 cpus, then it can get 500% max cpu usage. =/

Comment: Nothing. 6mb/s bandwidth in use / 20mb/s bandwidth total, 356% cpu in use / 500% total, 1.6gb memory in use / 7.4 gb total, Default configuration for apache worker, and no more than 2700 ~ 3000 users and it's crashing in the same way. Any solution???

Comment: The problem are not solved, but the configuration for 2000 concurrent users was made correctly by you. I'll try to build a load balancer. Big hug!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running out memory and apache is crashing because it using more than the available memory.

I am not very familiar with the worker mpm, but I think your configuration far exceeds your available memory.

For example, you have 5 threads per process, and 20000 MaxClient. That means that to serve your Max clients, you need `20000/5=4000` concurrent apache processes. Factoring in 13 GB memory (1 GB for system), and an average of 15MB for apache process size, you can serve about 4300 clients only.

I am assuming you are running a database there, too. This makes it logical for apache to die at around 3000 clients.

You should reduce the number of MaxClients and MinSpareThreads as @David Schwartz suggested.

Comment: Fine. I'll try this. In 30 minutes, I come back with the result.

Comment: Your configuration does not make any sense. You are trying to force threaded MPM to behave like a prefork MPM. Apache is crashing because you're trying to fork too many processes. This is not optimal. You shouldn't really have more than 1000 processes running on such system. You should probably read this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#threadsperchild

Comment: Fine. But what could be the ideal configuration for this demand?