# Is it viable to run a Web Server on AMD E-350 Dual Core Processor?

Tags: web-server, central-processing-unit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

I am trying to set up a small webserver using the AMD APU E-350 Dual Core @1.6GHz. I wish to know if it is a good option to go with for a server receiving almost like 500 visitors a day and at max, 25 simultaneous requests.

In all, the system will have a 4GB RAM, 60GB SSD and a gigagbit ethernet port.

Also, please suggest me a very lightweight linux OS and a web server for this configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: P.S: I am trying to run a wordpress blog on this hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you are serving, if it's just static files and only 500 visitors a day with a couple of requests each you can likely get away with pretty obsolete hardware. If the requests you are serving do heavy computation before serving the resulting page to the user you may want to look at other hardware. What you are serving as well as the number of concurrent requests is what is going to dictate your hardware and network needs.

I tend to use nginx for web serving on Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: I am trying to run a wordpress blog on this hardware