# optimizing xampp for high-traffic websites

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, xampp

There are lots of articles about optimizing apache for Linux. I am currently runing an xampp webserver, but I have no idea how to increase my apache speed and decrease my hardware usage.

I would like to be sure that my xampp configuration is in optimal and secure way.

Comment: Imposible to answer question. There is no way for us to tell if your app is cpu/memory or IO bound.

Comment: So this is why that i said . i would like to know how check my configure. if it is low hardware to buy higher . if it is enough! so optimize it

Answer (score 5):

**Don't Do That!** this is not XAMPP's mission.

From the Philosphy section of the website

> The philosophy behind XAMPP is to build an easy to install distribution for developers to get into the world of Apache. To make it convenient for developers XAMPP is configured with all features turned on.
>
> The default configuration is not good from a securtiy point of view and it's not secure enough for a production environment - please don't use XAMPP in such environment.

Note that it says *for developers...* and *not secure enough for production websites* so don't try and make it do something it's not designed for.

Sure, people will use it in production, people will use pretty much torture anything into production but that doesn't make it right.

Use the correct tools for the job, XAMPP for development and a suitably tuned web stack for production.

Further reading:

[Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

[How do you do load testing and capacity planning for web sites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)