# Hardware recommendation for Apache that handles large buffer requests

Tags: apache-2.2, hardware

I have some crawling nodes that send large chunks of POST messages to a PHP/Apache server 
running on Ubuntu

~ 200 requests each second ~ each request 100 lines of text .
currently for development I have a machine with 2 GB ram, but its stuck handling all these requests

How much ram is suitable for such a task ?

What CPU should I get ? currently (Pentium D :( )

any tips on network setup ?

currently the nodes are on the same LAN

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](http://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long is one line of that text?
First of all, enable compression, that You save bandwidth but cpu usage increases. try to measure how many memory need for single request processing. see [memory-get-peak-usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) and [memory-get-usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) then multiple this by ~ 200.
What php is doing with that lines of text? Intensive text processing ? or just store in database?
**First You must find bottleneck of your problem.**

Edit: what else is running on that dev machine?

Comment: php stores them in a mongodb database , line is ~ 150 character . I'll try the compression and report the get-peak-usage and memory-get-usage back

Comment: 150 characters * 100 lines is about 15KB * 200 reqests = ~ 3MB. You can try to disable unused php and apache modules.