# Server Hardware/Settings for high traffic

Tags: performance, central-processing-unit, virtualization

I'm currently using a virtual server.

> 2 vCores
>  8GB RAM
>  Bandwith 100MBit/s
>  Ubuntu 10.04

But still this seems to be not enough to handle the traffic on my site. Normally a page needs less than 0.2seconds to be generated, but when there are more visitors on the site at the same time, then it can also take sometimes more than 5 seconds.

> MySQL Statistics (approximately):
>  1300 queries/sec
>  80
>   connections simultaneously
>  CPU usage > 90 %

I have the possibility to upgrade to a better Virtual Server (4 vCores, 16GB RAM). Would this have much and visible effect on the performance?
Or is there any setting I could change in the apache config files?

Please tell me if you need any further information besides from that.

Comment: Load test your app in a test environment. No one is going to be able to answer you. Please see: http://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to jump out of a virtual server and grab a real server with SSD drives.

Cores won't matter if they are being rate limited.

Comment: No, the best way to do it is to collect metrics on your resource utilization, and then make decisions based on that. Throwing arbitrary hardware at the problem is very foolish.

Comment: Additionally, there are absolutely no guarantees that a "real server", by which I presume you meant "non-virtualized server" will perform any better than a VPS. I have VMs on both Linode and EC2 that will run circles around the machines peddled by many dedicated server providers.