# How can I find the bottle neck?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, web-server, php-fpm, bottleneck

I have a `EC2 m1.large Ubuntu 13.04` Instance runs `PHP 5.5`, `PHP-FPM` and `NGINX`. Cache is handled by `Elastic Cache` using `Redis` and the database connects to a separate `m1.large` `MongoDB` server. The content can be fairly dynamic as newsfeed can be dynamic and my server is used by an iOS app.

I am doing siege tests `siege -d5 -c150` if I do only 1 siege I see responses times that are less than 1 sec. If I add another server to do another `siege -d5 -c150` my response times go up the roof to 9-15 sec`

I am very new to servers setups but somethings tells me that if my server is always average of 40-50% CPU load and consuming under 1GB of ram. I shouldn't see 10++ sec latency having so much free resources?

What could be my bottle neck or even better how could I find it??

[image]
[image]

**/etc/sysctl.conf are**

```
 net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 2000 65000
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 3240000
net.core.somaxconn = 3240000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
kernel.shmmax = 1073741824
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 25165824 25165824
net.core.rmem_max = 25165824
net.core.rmem_default = 25165824
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 25165824
net.core.wmem_max = 25165824
net.core.wmem_default = 65536
net.core.optmem_max = 25165824
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 1474560    1966080    2949120
```

**/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 32
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 150
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 32768;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;

    server_tokens off;

    # allow the server to close the connection after a client stops responding. Frees up socket-associated memory.
    reset_timedout_connection on;


    # send the client a "request timed out" if the body is not loaded by this time. Default 60.
    client_body_timeout 10;

    # If the client stops reading data, free up the stale client connection after this much time. Default 60.
    send_timeout 10;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]";

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    server {
        listen 80 default;
        root /var/www/;
        index index.php index.htm index.html;

        # php-fpm bridge
        # execute all .php files with php-fpm
           location ~ .php$ {
              fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
              fastcgi_index  index.php;
              fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
              fastcgi_buffers 256  16k;
              fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
              fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
              include fastcgi_params;
           }
    }
}
```

**siege results**

```
ransactions:                    1265 hits
Availability:                  99.68 %
Elapsed time:                1196.10 secs
Data transferred:              21.30 MB
Response time:                 11.48 secs
Transaction rate:               1.06 trans/sec
Throughput:                     0.02 MB/sec
Concurrency:                   12.14
Successful transactions:        1265
Failed transactions:               4
Longest transaction:           26.88
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

Comment: One of your images is impossible to decipher, I have no idea what its showing.

Comment: @MIfe jsut changed the picture. it is my siege running verbose

Comment: @Magellan how is capacity planning and bottleneck assessment the same thing?

Comment: @JonathanThurft Capacity planning is all about predicting what you first bottleneck will be.  You have triggered your bottleneck with siege but you still don't know what it is. You are only looking at CPU and RAM.  [The top Website capacity planning answer](http://serverfault.com/a/350463/26130) has a list of resources that you should also be looking at.

Answer (score 0):

- test each component alone, and then all together.
- for each standalone test, make sure you simply test the pure performance, e.g. in nginx do

  ```
  location /perftest/ {
      return 200;
  }
  ```
- when your are sure, each component is tuned well, start combining them and test again

btw, are you using proper indizes on mongo?