# Can Apache Web Server handle up to 100,000 concurrent connections?

Tags: apache-2.2, connection, configuration

Is it possible to configure Apache Web Server to handle up to 100,000 or more concurrent connections?

I know if this were to be possible, it's definitely going to be resource intensive. In that case, what would be the most likely hardware configuration?

If it's not possible, then what is the maximum concurrent connections that Apache can be configured to handle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your idea of concurrent is probably not the same as Apache's idea of concurrent...

Comment: @ChrisS, I understand that Apache is designed as a Request/Response server. That noted, I believe it still has it's limits when used for long-polling. Why I asked this question is to know those limits. I visited the other question which you claim to be a duplicate and I did not see how it addresses my concern, neither are the answers a solution to my question. In my opinion, I don't see my question in anyway a duplicate to the question posted here [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the **questions** are the same; it's a duplicate because the **answers** are.  Noone can properly simulate your load like you can, so you will only get meaningful results by doing so.

Comment: @MadHatter, Thanks for your time and for clarifying some points. If I am certain about an answer, I wouldn't be posting this question in the first place. After going through the answers, none of them have still been able to address my question because of the manner the question they were answering was asked. Since, it has been said it's a duplicate and StackOverflowers who have answers can't get to respond to it, what do I then do now?

Comment: Set up your own capacity planning test rig.  The thrust of the answers we have referred you to is that noone can accurately help you on this particular issue except yourself.  You can of course buy in assistance in this, and many do, but the answers are always specific to the questioner, which is another reason why they're a bad fit for SF: **an answer precise and specific enough to be really helpful to you is useless to anyone else**.

Comment: Apache doesn't track connections, the operating system does. Most OSes take ~2kB to keep track of a connection and another 20-25kB in buffers. TCP connections have a maximum idle time before a packet is sent to verify that the connection is still alive, in the 100k range this becomes a noticeable amount of bandwidth. A quick Google for "linux guide to high concurrency tuning" brings up a number of pages detailing configuration issues that have to be fixed too.

Comment: @ChrisS, thanks for the explanation. In the end, I have no other choice than to accept you guys are right. There is no easy and direct answer. I will have to do more research, trial and error. My intention is to setup a server that can handle lots and lots of long-polling request.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the application that will be handling the long-polling request on the server is written in PHP, hence, my initial need for Apache.