# Optimize Apache for high concurrent requests

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, ulimit, mpm-prefork

I am running a Apache2 Ubuntu server which serves the API request from mobile apps.

Recently I am facing a bottleneck that when the request getting higher (more concurrent users), the request response is getting slow. Previously **~1 or 2** seconds will do, but once the concurrent users increase (at certain peak hour), it can delay up to **10** seconds or more, even-though the server load, **CPU** and **Memory** remains very low.

My target is to increase the capability of Apache2 and Ubuntu Server to serve **as much concurrent users as possible** at lowest response time. The **memory and CPU is not a major consideration factor** as the VPS specification can be scaled up if it hits the limit. How can I do that?

What I have done so far:

1. Configure ulimit **/etc/security/limits.conf** and add the following:

   - soft    nofile          40000
   - hard    nofile          40000
   - soft    nproc           40000
2. Add the following line to **/etc/pam.d/common-session**

   session required pam_limits.so
3. Configure Apache2 **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf**

```
    <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
            StartServers              20
            MinSpareServers           25
            MaxSpareServers          100
            MaxRequestWorkers         150
            MaxConnectionsPerChild   0

            MaxClients              8192
            MaxRequestsPerChild     0
            ServerLimit             8192
     </IfModule>
```

4. Add the following line to **/etc/sysctl.conf**

   fs.file-max = 2097152

The response time seems to be improved (though some requests still delayed), but not satisfactory as it is still much slower than non-peak hour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you do load testing and capacity planning for web sites?](http://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

Comment: Stop using prefork. It cannot keep up.

Answer (score 1):

Stop using prefork module and start using event mpm in apache.
Prefork is the old method and moving forward you want to install event mpm.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your web server but rather something else in the chain.

1. DNS. In situation, when it's not obviously the database, there is a good chance it is DNS. Do a nslookup and see how long the command takes. Then lookup a couple of domains.
2. Its the network, do a traceroute and see if any of the hops on your network are taking longer then usual.
3. `Netstat -i 5` to see if there are any errors on the network interface.
4. Make sure `KeepAlive` is on . Especially if you something like a ajax heavy site you will improve performance.

I don't believe switching MPM's will help you. Your situation isn't resource constraint. its something else.