# Apache htaccess redirect http/www to https/non-www

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To redirect from

```
 - http://www.domain.com
 - http://domain.com
 - https://www.domain.com
```

to https://domain.com

im using the following (apache)htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This works, but I think it's not the best way.
The first two sections would still be to combine, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Your use-case is the [**text-book example**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) of when to completely avoid rewrite rules.

> To redirect http URLs to https, simply do the following:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName www.example.com
>     Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:443>
>     ServerName www.example.com
>     # ... SSL configuration goes here
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

In addition: you should **avoid using .htaccess files completely** if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using `.htaccess` files [slows down](https://serverfault.com/a/780517/37681) your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.   **Source:** [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html)

For more information see the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [aaa](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html) documentation.