# .htaccess: password required two times for the redirect function

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.de/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access to /www.example.de"
AuthUserFile /myfolder/homepages/10/d563344564/htpasswd
Require user admin
```

If I reach example.de the system asks me the password twice (I guess the first for example.de and the second for www.example.de). But this happens also when in some images are loaded (the src attribute contains the link with www, but probably it is already changed because of .htaccess). Which way can I follow to have just one password request at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that basic authentication is specific for the protocol://host:port and realm combination and the login needs to be repeated for each variation. If your requests are mixed over `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` (and maybe even `httpS://www.example.com`) your user will always need to separately log into each.

The solution is stop using basic authentication and use a login form and set a session cookie that is valid for your domain and any/all subdomains. That is quite a bit more involved but still supported by a native apache module: [mod_auth_form](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_auth_form.html)

---

In response to your comment below:

`.htaccess` files are applicable to the directory they sit in (and any subdirectories found below that directory) , regardless of how you reach that directory.

If you want  certain directives to apply to a VirtualHost `example.com` and others to `www.example.com` you should forget about [the abomination](https://serverfault.com/questions/780459/load-time-impact-of-htaccess/780517#780517) that `.htaccess` files are and do what you should have been doing already, set your  directives in the `<VirtualHost>` entry in your main `httpd.conf` (or for instance the `sites-available/site.conf` include):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.de
     Redirect "/" "http://www.example.de/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.de
    DocumentRoot  /var/www/html

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Access to /www.example.de"
   AuthUserFile /myfolder/homepages/10/d563344564/htpasswd
   Require user admin

   ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: it's not possible to require the authentication, for example, only after the redirect when the link contains "www"?

Comment: `.htaccess` files are applicable to the directory they sit in (and any subdirectories found below that directory) , regardless of how you reach that directory. If you want  certain directives to apply to a VirtualHost `example.com` and others to `www.example.com` you should forget about [the abomination](http://serverfault.com/questions/780459/load-time-impact-of-htaccess/780517#780517) that `.htaccess` files are and do what you should have been doing already, set your  directives in the `<VirtualHost>` entry in your main `httpd.conf` (or for instance the `sites-available/site.conf` include)