# Secure all access to apache with basic authentication - directories and virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, http-basic-authentication

I want to use the apache server as web server and reverse proxy to several web-services.
But i also want use apache as an authentication gateway. I know how to protect specific directories with `.htaccess` or `<Directory>`. And i read how to protect specific `VirtualHost` with `<Location>`.

But is there a way to protect evrey access with same configuration - some kind of global basic authentication?

Comment: You can use the `Include` directive to include the same config into every VirtualHost

Comment: and whats about all hosted directories?

Comment: If you can't afford to completely [disable support for .htaccess files](http://serverfault.com/a/780517/37681) remove AuthConfig from what you allow in them by mdoifying your  [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) settings