# how to use rewrite files with lighttpd

Tags: http, rewrite, lighttpd

I have just installed a new personal Gentoo server (on a VPS at vpsfree.cz by the way) and wanted to try something more lightweight than Apache that I used on my previous Debian based server.

I used to generate apache rewrite files from my web tools in order to redirect browsers from obsolete URLs, remove `.html` from the URLs, and perform other magic. I stored those generated files inside the htdocs.

Now I'm experimenting with *lighttpd* and I'm looking for a decent solution. I like lighttpd otherwise but I would probably switch to something else if it won't fit the game.

Is it possible to use lighttpd in the same way as apache with generated rewrite/redirect rules? If not, is there a better solution?

Edit: So lighttpd doesn't support anything near Apache `.htaccess` files and I would probably have to create some per-project lighttpd configuration files and make lighttpd include those in its configuration, or I could use a different webserver (e.g. go back to Apache). I'm keeping the question open for now in case someone has some interesting solutions.

Edit: Are there some best practices regarding per-project or per-vhost rewrite configuration files included from lighttpd?

Comment: If your question is if `.htaccess` files are supported, [the answer is no](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Do-you-support-htaccess-files). No support for htaccess files is usually considered [a good thing](http://serverfault.com/a/780517/37681)

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't agree that a feature like `.htaccess` is bad. Rewrite/redirection rules are a natural part of a website (generated in my case) and not of the server configuration as they do change when the website source data change. – Thanks for the link about performance penalty in Apache. I don't currently need to optimize to such a level. – Anyway the link to FAQ answers the question for lighttpd at the least.