# How many people can a normal laptop server serve?

Tags: windows, load-testing, laptop

I'm just trying to play around with my laptop by hosting a small WordPress blog on that. I wonder how many people it can serve at once.

About the network, I've tested on Speedtest.net and got this result:
https://www.speedtest.net/result/8478472643

About the hardware, it runs on Windows 10 Pro 64bit, Intel Core i5-7200U, 8GB of RAM, and 1TB Samsung QVO SSD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you do load testing and capacity planning for web sites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites) - somewhere between none and many depending on how you configure your service, which optional WP modules etc,  With the right optimization probably many, out of the box fewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your WordPress setup and configuration - and what your users are going to do with it.

A simple and plain WordPress on a i5 Windows 10 (IIS/PHP7nts) may serve tens of thousands of users, but if they are searching the site, doing a lot of logins of use the comment function heavily, this may shrink to a few hundered parallel users.

Bandwith will most probably not the bottleneck in this case, nor will latency. I'd bet on CPU/RAM as the constraing factor.

Comment: Wow that's a lot for me