# What's the more decisive server hardware vector for heavy load production webserver performance

Tags: apache-2.4, hardware, debian-buster

I'm about to buy new server hardware and I was wondering, in your opinion, and reducting problem to one machine (that's it, no more complex network infraestructure in play) what's the local server hardware more important's vector for server performance: memory, CPU, CPU tech, HD space, HD tech.. Where the focus should mainly be pointed at?

Server will be running Debian 10, just Apache 2.4.4 & shell services, and will handle +300 average concurrent clients.

**Edited:**

Got suggested this post to me as a possible duplicate: [How do you do load testing and capacity planning for web sites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

; I wannna clarify that I'm not asking for an actual hardware configuration, not a guide, not load balancing tools to help decissions on upgrades:
but for the vector that you'd give priority to give extra air to a heavy loaded standalone apache server (no more services, nor mysql..).
The vector you think affects more perfomance on Apache.

I have my own opinion and wanted to hear yours, but I recognize this debate could not be useful for majority, maybe the thread should be closed.

Comment: Unless your web sites/applications are doing very CPU intensive stuff more cores wil often  give you more performance than fewer with a higher clock frequency. Unless you have enormously large datasets and your budget doesn't stretch infinitely  SSD / NVME storage is preferable over spinning disks. Server CPU's are prefered over dekstop CPU's for server workloads and for web loads GPU's are probably not needed. Too little RAM is disastrous, whatever you buy too much won't  exactly be wasted and will used for caching, but that might make an expensive cache

Comment: Damn - I was a few thousand chars into a long answer - oh well

Comment: @Chopper3 you can always add such an answer to the linked duplicate or cast a re-open vote