# Server architecture for high traffic system

Tags: linux, nginx, haproxy, dedicated-server, laravel

we are working on the online exam system, which supposed to have much traffic at the same times, more than 15000 students will log in and make an exam at the same time,
we are developing this system using laravel + MySQL database.
recently we purchase a dedicated server with 64G ram, 42 core.
what is the best architecture for this dedicated server to handle these many requests at the same time , I am thinking to install containers inside that server and split it as

> 2 containers as web servers with Nginx and apply load balance between
> them using haproxy . 2 for MySQL database and apply load balancing. 1
> for cache server using Redis server

but I am not sure if this way is good or not.
please advise me to handle this issue, I am waiting for your recommendation
best regards

Comment: Interesting post, but don't be surprised if it gets closed as it invites discussion rather than asking a specific question.  And honestly, lacks a lot of details to  even generate an _informed_ discussion.

Comment: @BrandonXavier thank you for your attention , actually I can not provide more details , I typed all things that  can describe the problem , with the hardware resources

Comment: In general you select a technology that you are familiar with unless you have a lot of time to build up new expertise. Then a rinse-and-repeat cycle of improving your application, load/stress testing and benchmarking your application, adjusting and improving your tuning, code and settings. There is no a-priori reason that your hardware will be either be insufficient or more than capable enough, but generally I would expect that default settings and bad code will almost certainly show (severe) bottlenecks the first time you apply more load than a single developer testing from his laptop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you do load testing and capacity planning for web sites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

Comment: You use a cloud, and scale up when there are exams, and scale down when there are not exams.