# How much traffic can a heroku page handle?

Tags: heroku

I have recently deployed my rails website with Heroku.

I am currently on the paid Hobby Dyno.

My web page consits of a log in function, 13 five minute long sound files, a few images and a bunch of zoom links. I am expecting around 200 users at any given time clicking around the pages.

Will the hobby dyno be enough for this or should I invest is something more expensive?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider storing the large files off site, in something like Amazon S3, or putting a CDN like CloudFlare in front of them. Whether a hobby dyno can handle this sort of traffic depends heavily on how frequently your 200 users are clicking around, the file sizes involved, the skill of your coding, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you do load testing and capacity planning for web sites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

Comment: @ceejayoz, All of the files are stored off site. Im not expecting a lot of users to click around at the same time, as the majority of the time they will be sat in zoom meetings. Does this help you gice me more advice?