# What is the ideal value for threads on thread_pool in nginx config?

Tags: nginx, optimization

I have a machine with 2x CPU 24 Cores, 48 Threads

Total: 48 Cores, 96 Threads.

My nginx default configuration came configured with `threads=32`

```
thread_pool pool_name threads=32 max_queue=0;
```

Should i change my nginx config file from `threads=32` to `threads=96`?

Comment: ***"should I change my nginx config"***  - only when you have performance problems. *Note:*  Tuning is both a black art and a science and the "best" configuration depends on your load and usage patterns. The normal approach is to "do a load test" with your current configuration,  "make an adjustment"  in your configuration, run a "new load test", "compare results". Rinse and repeat until you find optimum settings. See https://serverfault.com/q/350454/960939 -

Comment: It depends on your needs, application configuration, load, etc. You don't want to use your options blindly. Also, I believe, there are another applications, programs, etc. executing parallel to your web-server, they need some computing power too.